# What is the proper way to embed tabs in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'd like to statically embed two tabs in my application and be informed when the tabs change but I don't know how to do it maintaining all the MVVM rules.

I have `MainViewModel` which inherits from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`

then I've got my sub viewmodels `FirstViewModel` and `SecondViewModel` which inherits from `Screen`.

Now my `MainView` looks simply like this:

`<TabControl x:Name="Items" />`

and I attach my views in its vm constructor:

```
Items.AddRange(
    new IScreen[]
    {
        new FirstViewModel(events),
        new SecondViewModel(events)
    });
```

But this way I need to pass `events` (`EventAggregator`) in params.

I'd like to be able to use `[ImportingConstructor]` to do it automatically.

Also it doesn't look right for me to create those viewmodels in code. I think I should specify those tabs directly in `MainView` but when I do it like this I can't take adventage of `Conductor.Collection.OneActive` and `Screen`'s events like `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your event aggregator is a singleton, then you leave it up to MEF to resolve your dependencies by injecting the `FirstViewModel` and `SecondViewModel` into the `MainViewModel` via constructor injection.

As these both have a dependency on `IEventAggregator`, that will also be resolved as part of the construction of `MainViewModel`.

If you have a specific instance of the event aggregator that you need to inject, or you wish to control the instantiation of the child view models from the `MainViewModel`, then you should introduce a view model factory which is injected into your `MainViewModel`.